# How to execute my fragment onClick action inside of Main Class?

Tags: android, kotlin

`Fragment` onClick fails with below error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: farenheitView must not be null
        at com.example.MainActivity.celsiusFunction(MainActivity.kt:68)
```

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PostAdapter.OnPostClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    val dummyList = createMockData()
    val adapter = PostAdapter(dummyList, this)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val tempConverter = TempConverterFragment()
        val recyclerView = RecyclerViewFragment()
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        val uploaderView = UploaderFragment(this)
        setFragmentView(recyclerView)

        binding.bottomNavBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.listView ->  setFragmentView(recyclerView)
                R.id.tempConverterView -> setFragmentView(tempConverter)
                R.id.videoUploaderView -> setFragmentView(uploaderView)
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun setFragmentView(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.main_fragment_view, fragment)
            //Will return to previous page when tap "Back Button" on the phone
            addToBackStack(null)
            commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onEditPost(position: Int){
        val clickedPost = dummyList[position]
        clickedPost.title = "Updated title"
        clickedPost.body = "Updated body"
        adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
    }

    override fun onDeletePost(position: Int) {
        dummyList.removeAt(position)
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    fun celsiusFunction(view: View){
        val farenheitView = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userTemp)
        val farenheitValue = farenheitView.text.toString()

        if(!farenheitValue.isBlank()){
            val celsiusCovertedValue = (farenheitValue.toDouble() - 32) * 5/9
            val celsiusValue = String.format("%.2f", celsiusCovertedValue)
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "$farenheitValue fahrenheit is $celsiusValue degrees celsius",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter a value to convert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun farenheitFunction(view: View){
        val celsiusView = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userTemp)
        val celsiusValue = celsiusView.text.toString()

        if(!celsiusValue.isBlank()){
            val farenheitConvertedValue = celsiusValue.toDouble() * 9/5 + 32
            val farenheitValue = String.format("%.2f", farenheitConvertedValue)
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "$celsiusValue degrees celsius is $farenheitValue farenheit",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter a value to convert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my tempConverter class:

```
class TempConverterFragment: Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_temp_converter, container, false)
        return binding
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity` xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is where I implement my `TempConverter` function:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="487dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/termometer" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
    android:text="Enter desired temperature to convert"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userTemp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Temperature Here"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
    android:singleLine="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/celsiusButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:onClick="celsiusFunction"
    android:text="to Celsius"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/farenheitButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userTemp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/farenheitButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="72dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
    android:onClick= "farenheitFunction"
    android:text= "to Farenheit"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/teal_200"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/celsiusButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userTemp" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

So my app layout have a `BottomNavBar`. And each Navbar have it's own fragment. One is a `RecyclerView`, a `TempConverter` view and `ImageUploader` view. How to implement the fragment activity correctly and what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Hi as I can see from your logcat you are getting your `fahrenhit` view as null. See this lines :- `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: farenheitView must not be null
        at com.example.MainActivity.celsiusFunction(MainActivity.kt:68)`

Comment: I assume line number 68 in your `mainActivity` is this lines :- `val farenheitView = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.userTemp)
        val farenheitValue = farenheitView.text.toString()` from where are you calling this function ?

Comment: I calling it from my main class

Comment: Please add that code I don't see it in your `MainActivity` also please check if you are using same `id` in your `xml` as well. it should be `userTemp` boths

Comment: I have add the main class code above in the celsius() function . I will check again my id

Comment: I still don't see from where are you calling your `celsiusFunction` can you point that out ?

Comment: If you look after onDeletePost function, you will find the celsius function and on line 1 inside of that function. Also I just notice that my bind cannot detect the userTemp id. How to make a bind detect fragment xml Id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228783/discussion-between-mohammed-hanif-and-aiman-irfan).

Answer (score 1):

from the logcat you can see that it says your `farenheitView`  is null and that's waht causing the error. Now as per the `xml` and your `MainActivity` it's clear that you have your `farenheitView` in your `fragment` but you are trying to get that in your `MainActivity` which is the reason you are getting `null` value there.

Instead what you need to do is you need to have your functions of the fragments inside your `fragment` class only and not in your `mainActivity` class and you can call them wherever you need in that `fragment`.

Also I would suggest you to use `bindings` in your `fragments` as well as i can see you have already used that in your `mainActivity`.

You can learn more about `Fragments` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments) and [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments) (Also there are tons of other blogs and tutorials out there).

Happy Coding !